# Is "entitled" a verb or adjective or both in "She is entitled..."?

Tags: sentence-structure, parts-of-speech

> She is entitled to all luxuries in her life.

What is the voice of the sentence?
If it is passive, which word is the main verb in the sentence?

In this sentence the word "entitled" is used as adjective,  without the adjective the sentence has the complete  meaning. If so without "entitled" the above sentence's meaning should be complete but it is not the case. Is the word "entitled" also a verb?

Answer (score -1):

Study the sentence.
She is grateful to her friends. If the adjective grateful is removed from the sentence it will become meaningless. In the same manner entitled is used as an adjective.

Comment: "is grateful" and "is entitled" are different grammar constructions  'grateful' is an adjective, and 'entitle/d' is a verb.

Answer (score -1):

**She *is entitled* to all luxuries in her life.**

"...is entitled" in this sentence is what is known as a **verbal**.   A verbal is a participle verb phrase (-ed, -en, -d, -t, -n, or sometimes -ne) which functions as an *adjective*.  Adjectives describe the state or characteristics of a noun.   Specifically, a verbal describes a state of being.

This is similar to the passive voice, where (to be + participle) constructions are used to connect a verb directly with its object:

**The lion was killed by the hunter**.
**The lion was killed.**

The subject of the verb in the active form of the sentence:

**The hunter killed the lion.**

can be removed completely.

In the "entitled... to luxuries", the verb is not transitive - it just describes a state of being. No one is "entitling" the subject.  So, this cannot be considered passive voice.  *Non-transitive verbs cannot be passive*.

Compare:

**When it came time for his turn, *he was skipped over***.

**My cat *will be full-grown*, soon!**

It's a little bit confusing here however, because "entitle" also has a transitive form:

**The Constitution entitles all to equal protection under the law.**

If something is *doing* the entitling, then you could possible hear the example in the question as passive.  This would be especially true if the sentence was past-tense - some real ambiguity would be present.

Comment: Please explain your downvote so the answer can be improved.